# How to return all elements in function-created list by their name?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created the following example function:

```
my_function <- function(input_1, input_2){

a <- input_1*2
b <- input_2*3
c <- input_2*10

return(list(a = a, b = b, c = c))

}
```

How can I save all the elements of the resultant list to the working environment without doing so manually? To do it by brute force, I would just do:

```
func_list <- my_function(input_1 = 5, input_2 = 6)
a <- func_list$a
b <- func_list$b
c <- func_list$c
```

In the project I'm working on, I need to return a lot of objects into the environment (either the global environment or in a function), so doing so manually every time is not feasible. Is there a way to return all the items at once? Would it be possible, also, to return all objects created within the function itself (and not have to make a return list that specifies every object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save them as vectors directly in your enviroment you coud use the operator `<<-`

```
my_function <- function(input_1, input_2){
  
  a <<- input_1*2
  b <<- input_2*3
  d <<- input_2*10
  
}

my_function(input_1 = 5, input_2 = 6)
```

But be careful since this could be dangerous if not properly used, also `c` is already a function in R, so don't use as variable name!

Comment: Does this save them in the global environment or within the local environment? In my case I'd want to run this function inside of another function, so it'd be ideal to return the vectors solely within the environment of that function.

Answer (score 0):

As the function is returning a named list, use `list2env`

```
list2env(my_function(input_1 = 5, input_2 = 6), .GlobalEnv)
```

-checking

```
> a
[1] 10
> b
[1] 18
> c
[1] 60
```

---

Or another option is to specify an environment

```
my_function <- function(input_1, input_2, env = parent.frame())
    {
env$a <- input_1*2
env$b <- input_2*3
env$c <- input_2*10


}
```

-testing

```
> rm(a, b, c)
> my_function(input_1 = 5, input_2 = 6)
> a
[1] 10
> b
[1] 18
> c
[1] 60
```